# Genetic algorithm producing irregular result in finding the maxima of a multivariable function

Tags: python, optimization, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

I'm trying to implement a genetic algorithm in order to find the maxima of this function

```
 f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^3 + z^4 + xyz on [0,10] [0,20] [0,30] for x,y,z respectively
```

my objective function is the same as the function above. Each `x,y,z` of the population is represented by a binary string which is initialized randomly.

I've implemented it like this:

> 1. Roulette wheel selection
> 2. Single point crossover (no crossover rate)
> 3. Mutation: If the chromosome (x,y,z) is selected for mutation I flip a random bit of x, a random bit of y and a random bit of z.

I've noticed that giving the bigger z exponent, it is the first variable to converge. The rest of them have trouble converging as generations go by. Is this an acceptable behavior?

[image]

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SVD8.png)

Comment: Do you already know that the maximum for your optimization problem is `f(10,20,30)=824100`?

Comment: No, that is not known by the algorithm if that's what you mean.

Comment: Reaching 819234 out of 824100 is pretty typical for a genetic algorithm. Note that mutations help keep the algorithm from getting stuck at a local maximum. But your objective function is strictly increasing in all three inputs, so there are no local maxima to avoid. You could try disabling mutations, and see how that affects the outcome. Mutations can be counterproductive as the algorithm approaches the global maximum.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. This is my first encounter with GAs, thus the confusion.

Comment: How do you ensure that the variables intervals are respected? I mean: if for example `x>10`, you kill the individual or you set `x=10`?

Comment: Individuals are generated randomly. Each individual is a list of [x, y, z] and each list variable is a string of 0s and 1s. The number of bits (string length) is predetermined and is the same for each  variable x, y or z which are then decoded to real values: 


`real_val = lower_bound +(decimal_representation/(2^bits) * (upper_bound - lower_bound)`

e.g.
If x="11111" (bounds are [0, 10])  then its decimal representation is 31 and real value is: 
0 + ( 31/32 ) * (10-0) = 9.6875 which is the biggest real value X can take given 5 bits  representation.